# Checkbox functionality not working when parent has a click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a checkbox inside a div which has a click event attached to it. But the checking and unchecking the checkbox directly doesn't work.

```
<div class="container" onclick="select(this)">
     <input type="checkbox" value="" /><label>Item</label>
</div>

function select(e) {
    var elm = $(e);
    var chkBox = elm.find('input');
    console.log(chkBox.is(':checked'));
    if(chkBox.is(':checked')) {
       chkBox.prop("checked", false);
   }else{
       chkBox.prop("checked", true);
   }
}
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/h45A5/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to bind event properly rather than using an inline handler,

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
    <input type="checkbox" value="" /><label>Item</label>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$('div.container').click(function(e){
   if($(e.target).is(':checkbox')){ return; }
   var chkBox = $(this).find(':checkbox');
   chkBox.prop("checked", !chkBox.is(':checked'));
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/laraprabhu/h45A5/14/)

Answer (score 2):

You should write  `var elm = getElementById('e');` instead of var `elm = $(e);`

Try it yourself: http://jsfiddle.net/h45A5/3/

Comment: i want the checkbox to be checked even when the container is selected and also when the checkbox is checked.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want the checkbox to toggle if either the `div` and the `checkbox` are clicked, in which case, add

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

[Refer updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h45A5/23/)